# What is the best way to create a location in Blender or Unity?

Tags: unity, blender, level-design, 3d-modeling

I am new to this, and the task before me was to create a laboratory location. Here I have a question, what is the best way to implement this? I've heard about Unity ProBuilder, but I've also heard the opinion that locations should be created in Blender. By laboratory building, I mean rooms (walls, floor, ceiling), as, for example, made in Black Mesa.

Comment: Does these past Q&A help you? [Working with Blender (Model individual objects or scenes?)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/151521/39518) or [How should I make (3D) buildings that can be entered in the game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/143007/39518)

Comment: @DMGregory, thanks for trying to help, however, this is not what I need. I'm wondering how it's easier to implement a game location. To give another example, I'm asking how it's easier to build a house using Blender or Probuilder.

Comment: But what is the goal of your location? To be able to interact with it? Navigate around? Be used as a background? Able to place build at runtime? Use as components for building bigger similar rooms?

Comment: How would you describe the difference between "a game location" for your purposes, versus "3D buildings that can be entered in the game"? The more precisely you cen define how your needs differ from these existing Q&A threads, the better we can tailor answers to serve those needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow I would use is:

1. Create the basic blockout (floors, walls, ceilings) in Unity using Pro Builder and/or Polybrush.
2. Place cubes in the blockout as stand-ins for furniture
3. Playtest the level to make sure it does its job from a gameplay perspective, probably making a couple adjustments regarding what to place where and if at all.
4. Create all the more detailed 3d objects (furniture, lab equipment...) in Blender.
5. Import the models into Unity and replace the placeholder cubes with the actual 3d models.